# Making Datepicker Options,minDate and maxDate Dynamic in Odoo

Tags: odoo-12

I have a selection field that selects months from one to twelve.According to the selected value,only some dates related to that value shoud be enabled and other dates should be disabled.In datepicker options, if I add static minDate and maxDate ,they work.But how do I make them dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using js if you are using web by getting value of the year field and set min max accordingly